# Target feature can be label-encoded then apply one-hot encoding afterwards

Tags: pandas, numpy, target

I want to apply a decision tree classifier, after I label-encode the target feature to 0,1,2,3 can i apply one-hot encoding to it again? is that allowed?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to use sklearn decision tree classifier?

Answer (score 2):

There should be only one target column. After applying One Hot Encoding on Target Column, it will create three new target columns which is not the correct way.